# Is $\mathbb Z$ the only proper sub-domain ( a subring that is an integral domain ) with unity of the ring $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: ring-theory, rational-numbers, integral-domain, integers

Is $\mathbb Z$ the only proper sub-domain ( a subring that is an integral domain ) with unity of the ring $\mathbb Q$ ? ( I can easily prove that if $D$ is any subring with unity then $\mathbb Z \subseteq D$ but cannot seem to apply integral domain condition to conclude the reverse )

Comment: Certainly not; for instance every localization at a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ is (isomorphic to) a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @egreg: I believe your comment is an answer.

Comment: @egreg: Strange ; an old abstract algebra book of W.E. Deskins gives this excercise " Prove that the only proper subdomain of the integral domain of the rational numbers is the ring of rational integers "

Comment: @user123733 The book is wrong.

Comment: @egreg: off-course , it is clear now

Answer (score 1):

Any subring of a field is a domain, so it's not surprising you can't apply the condition.

If $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ (with $0\notin S$), then
$$
S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}=\left\{\frac{a}{b}\;\middle|\; a\in\mathbb{Z}, b\in S\right\}
$$
is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $\mathbb{Z}$.

A non trivial example of $S$ is $S=\mathbb{Z}\setminus p\mathbb{Z}$, with $p$ a prime, so $S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$ is (isomorphic to) the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the prime ideal $p\mathbb{Z}$.

Other examples are $S=\{c^n\mid n\ge0\}$, where $c\ne0$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's false: any ring of fractions $S^{-1}\mathbf Z$ of $\mathbf Z$ is strictly between  $\mathbf Z$ and  $\mathbf Q$ as soon as $S$ is different from $\{1-,1\}$ and $S$ is a saturated multiplicative part different from $\mathbf Z\setminus{0}$. Most notable examples are  $\mathbf Z[\frac1n]$ (fractions with denominator a power of $n$) and, for a prime $p$,  $\mathbf Z_{(p)}$, the set of fractions with denominator *not* divisible by $p$. These are *local* rings, i.e. they have only one maximal ideal.

Comment: The condition for strict inclusion is more complicated: e.g. if $S = \{ x^2 \mid x \in \mathbf{Z} \wedge x \neq 0 \}$, then you still get $S^{-1} \mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: Also, $\mathbf{Z}_n$ is usually used for the $n$-adics or for the integers modulo $n$. I don't think I've ever seen it used for $\mathbf{Z}[1/n]$.

Comment: @Hurkyl:You're right; it's only a very general notation. As for the strict inclusion, I was thinking of a saturated multiplicative part. I'll fix that in a moment.